# Show record from database base on selected item in JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, database, jcombobox

I'm having a problem showing the record in my database when the user select an item in the JCombobox. The items in the jcombobox are the ID numbers in my database. I successfully(hope so!) put all the id's in the jcombobox and the first item shows all the corresponding data in it but when i change the item(ID#), it's corresponding data doesn't change. Nothing happens. The record that shows up is still the data from the first item(ID) that was selected. Also how can i make the jcombobox select no item on its execution(when the app is running)? Here's my current code so far:

```
        Class.forName(driverName); 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    String sql = "SELECT Emp_ID FROM employee ORDER BY Emp_ID";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        empID = rs.getString("Emp_ID");

        // Add the data to the combocox
        // cmbEmpID is the jcombobox
        cmbEmpID.addItem(empID);

    }

    String id = cmbEmpID.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String sql2 = " SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Emp_ID = " + id;

    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        empID = rs.getString("Emp_ID");
        empName = rs.getString("Emp_Name");
        empRate = rs.getInt("Emp_Rate");

        txtName.setText(empName);
        txtRate.setText(String.valueOf(empRate));
    }
}
```

Comment: just check that String id is getting changed after selection of the item in the combobox

Comment: @swapnil7 How would i do that? Can you provide some code?

Comment: @ wapnil7 Do i have to add an item listener to the jcombobox?

Comment: print the value of the id on the console

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make the jcombobox select no item on its execution(when the
>   app is running)?

```
 comboxname.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

By default selected index is 0 , so it selects first item.
If you dont want any item by default selected set selected index =-1

Comment: It works. Now my only problem is how to show up the data when the user choose an item.

Comment: now check whether id string is updating as per selection by printing id on the console

Comment: I tried it and it changes the id in the console when i changed the item selected. But data is not shown. By the way i didn't notice that when i set the index to -1. it gives an error but the app still runs. Maybe it conflicts to the database?

Comment: set selectedIndex value at time of form loading , are you using netbeans

Comment: Okay. I'll try it. I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts, for what it's worth

For the following line:

```
String sql2 = " SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Emp_ID = " + id;
```

variable id needs to be enclosed in single quotation marks if it represents a string from a multicharacter field for the SQL to work,

Line should read

```
String sql2 = " SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Emp_ID = " + "'" + id + "'";
```